# How to get the boot logs for a 16.04 system that won't boot?

Tags: boot

I have a boot issue such that my 15.10 system won't boot. I want to check the logs to look for clues but apparently I need the system to boot so that I can use journalctl

Obviously that's not a workable arrangement. Surely someone wasn't silly enough to create a boot log system that was dependant on booting succeeding???

Anyway... How can I read the boot logs?

Comment: Have you tried other boot options in grub? with previous kernel?

Comment: 16.04 or 15.10?

Comment: technically 15.04 but close enough as it's supposed to be the same just they're called different things. Tried every boot option but there was no way to get in so i'm rebuilding.

Answer (score 1):

**Boot from a live CD/USB Ubuntu**

1. Change the BIOS Boot Order or use the Boot Menu to boot from your Ubuntu Desktop CD / DVD
2. Chose "**Try Ubuntu**"
3. From **Nautilus** File Manager, click on the partitions under the menu **DEVICES** like in the image below
   [image]
4. Find your **/** partition and go to var/log check for logs
5. Check if you find any clue in boot.log, dmesg, kern.log and syslog

Above was the answer to your question, but i think you should try another approach like: [Ubuntu Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Please expand this answer with further information on how to accomplish the actions described by you.

Comment: And then drop us a comment and we'll come back and upvote!  ;)

Comment: i Assumed that @m12lrpv has some knowledge about Ubuntu since he asked how can read the log files to find any clue about his boot issue, for this reason i did't respond with a proper how to. Sorry about that

Comment: I can get to /var/logs by sticking the disk in another linux box (actually a prior image of my own system) but the logs are no longer updated with boot information after 14.?? so they don't hold any useful information relative to the issue.
Boot repair couldn't fix it.

Comment: There's too much config in the more recent system that I wanted to fix what the issue was rather than rebuild and hoped the logs would do what logs do but sadly it seems ubuntu has adopted a system that requires the system to be able to boot in order to view the logs. Surely someone in the meeting that developed that "feature" could have suggested that it was a really silly idea.
As per comment on question i'm rebuilding.

Comment: Can you tell us at least where your sistem it hangs out? Any useful info, a message on screen , anything?

Comment: I think my response was fair enough for your question but you didn't asked the correct question Although i see your point now...